# Style link as submit button

Tags: css, firefox

I have a link and a submit button styled with the same `.button` class. Is there an easy way to make them look exactly the same (to have a same height)?

```css
body .button {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 15px;
    background: #3333CC;
    border-color: #5033CC;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 11px;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 4px 7px 4px 7px;
    cursor: pointer;
    min-width: 90px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form>
<a class="button" href="http://www.example.org">Link as button</a>
<input class="button" type="submit" value="button as button"/>
</form>
```

EDIT: I just found out that they look the same in Google Chrome, but not in Firefox.

Comment: They look the same for me.

Comment: They look the same already. Well, you can use a ui framework like bootstrap or can just use ui components like http://purecss.io/buttons/

Comment: They dont look the same also in Chrome. Other than different fonts, there's a problem with the different width/height. It is caused because the browser calculates width/height as `width + paddings + margins + borders` for the button and not for the link. Adding `box-sizing` solves this issue. See my answer please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>In this example, they do have the same height (25pixels). You can always set a height in the CSS.</strike>

One thing you missed is changing the font-family.

In this example I've added one just to Helvetica, but that will make them more similar.

You can set `box-sizing:border-box`, set a solid height (`25px` in this example) and then change `display:inline-block;` to `float:left;`

```css
body .button {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 15px;
    background: #3333CC;
    border-color: #5033CC;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 11px;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 4px 7px 4px 7px;
    cursor: pointer;
    min-width: 90px;
    text-decoration: none;
    float:left;
    font-family:'Helvetica';
    box-sizing:border-box;
    height:25px;
}
```

```html
<form>
<a class="button" href="http://www.example.org">Link as button</a>
<input class="button" type="submit" value="button as button"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for ultra quick answer, but this still doesn't work in firefox (http://i.imgur.com/sMjmpFe.png).

Comment: Will look into it now :) @GuirNab